# Migration using AWS-DMS from standalone SQL server to AWS Redshift?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, database-migration, aws-dms

I have a SQL Server 2012 hosted on a standalone machine. I want to migrate it to my AWS Redshift (already existing data warehouse).

My question is wether it is possible via AWS Data migration service ?

I am also open to other efficient methods for migration. Currently I am doing the following steps

1. taking a backup of the SQL server DB in the standalone server.
2. uploading it to AWS-S3.
3. Droping and restoring the Db from S3 in AWS-RDS (Sql-server)

I would like this data to be present in my data warehouse i.e AWS-Redshift

Thanks for the help in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 types of migration within DMS

- "one off" data migration, where the data is copied using sql
  statements
- "continuous replication", where the "change dta capture" system on
  the source is used to capture and process just the updates.

SQL server can be used as a source for both of these types however there are caveats and limitations that should be read and understood thoroughly.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html

So long as you follow the instructions and meet the limitiations that are documented then it will work great.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question has been answered over five years ago and the accepted answer is still valid, even despite all of the changes that have happened in those five years.

For others finding this topic today, I would like to add an alternative method, for the sake of completeness:

1. Dump the data from Microsoft SQL Server
2. Convert the dumped file into some compressed format supported by the Redshift Copy command (e.g., Parquet)
3. Copy the resulting file to S3
4. Use the copy command to load the data into Redshift